# How can I arrange this text in 2 columns?

Tags: html, css

This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=14

This is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/s0bsfdu4/

This is an image that I want to understand how I want to arrange text

http://i60.tinypic.com/308w3d2.jpg

Code HTML:

```
    <p id="text3">Am reprezentat şi am acordat consultanţă juridică pentru clienţi persoane fizice române şi străine, instituţii publice, persoane juridice române şi străine în următoarele domenii:
<br><br>

- agricultură, exploatări agricole, prelucrarea şi comercializarea produselor agricole;
<br>
- comerţ cu produse alimentare;
<br>
- imobiliar;
<br>
- distribuţie de carburanţi;
<br>
- transporturi;
<br>
- asigurări;
<br>
- producţie şi comercializare utilaje grele;
<br>
- producţie structuri metalice;
<br>
- producţie automatizări;
<br>
- servicii de proiectare;
<br>
- comercializare automatizări;
<br>
- jocuri de noroc;
<br>
- turism, hoteluri şi pensiuni;
<br>
- medical;
<br>
- construcţii civile şi industriale;
<br>
- comercializare utilaje şi autovehicule, service auto;
<br>
- producţie software, administrarea site-urilor;
<br>
- comerţ;
<br>
- bursier, societăţi listate, investitori, fonduri de investiţii.
<br>
- asistenţă şi îngrijire copii şi vârstnici;
<br>
- exploatări forestiere şi prelucrarea lemnului;
<br>
- exploatări agricole;
<br>
- extracţia şi prelucrarea minereurilor;
<br>
- producţia şi comercializarea materialelor de construcţii;
<br>
- instituţii publice;
<br>
- instituţii religioase.</p>
```

Code CSS:

```
#text3{
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
column-count: 3;font-size: 17px;padding: 45px;margin: 100px;width: 80%;}
```

Basically I want to arrange text in 3 columns ... the first column to be selected text in the image and the rest of the text to be divided into 2 columns.

It can do this in CSS?

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your HTML had a regular structure , things would be much easier. here you can try to get the second of first br with nth-child :http://jsfiddle.net/s0bsfdu4/9/ or  http://jsfiddle.net/s0bsfdu4/8/ . This should not be taken as an answer, you should properly build your HTML with <p> or list :)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your `fiddle`. Check if is ok [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/s0bsfdu4/6/)